# how to detect collison in JAVA?

Tags: java

I just want to make ball break into two pieces when balls meet
this is my Ball Thread code and then,

```
class Ball extends Thread
    {   
        public Ball(Canvas c,double ran1,double ran2)   { box = c; num1=ran1; num2=ran2;}
        public void draw()
        {   
            Graphics g = box.getGraphics();
            g.fillOval(x, y, XSIZE, YSIZE);
            g.dispose();    
        }
        public void move(double drx,double dry)
        {   
            Graphics g = box.getGraphics();
            g.setXORMode(box.getBackground());
            g.fillOval(x, y, XSIZE, YSIZE);
            x += dx*drx;    y += dy*dry;
            Dimension d = box.getSize();
        if (x < 0){ 
            x = 0; 
            dx = -dx; 
        }
        if (x + XSIZE >= d.width){ 
            x = d.width - XSIZE; 
            dx = -dx; 
        }
        if (y < 0) { 
            y = 0; 
            dy = -dy; 
        }
        if (y + YSIZE >= d.height) { 
            y = d.height - YSIZE; 
            dy = -dy; 
        }
        g.fillOval(x, y, XSIZE, YSIZE);
        g.dispose();    
        }
        public void run()
        {   
            draw();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
            {   
                move(num1,num2);
                try { Thread.sleep(10); } catch(InterruptedException e) {}
            } 
        }
    }
```

then how to detect collsion?

```
public boolean crashCheck(Ball b1,Ball b2)
```

I try this but it hard to create

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried? To get my head around collision boxing many years ago, I found that drawing two squares on some graph paper helped me work through the test.

Comment: Class `Ball` really should not be a `Thread`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I don't know what your ball's attributes are, but if we consider you know the center point and the radius of the ball you can easily detect the collision.
Indeed, you just have to compute the distance between the two centres and checks whether it is greater than the two radiuses. If you don't have the necessary attributes in your class, you should update your class so that it contains these informations.
Code would be:

```
//compare the distance to combined radii
if ( Math.sqrt( ( b2.x-b1.x ) * ( b2.x-b1.x )  + ( b2.y-b1.y ) * ( b2.y-b1.y ) ) < ( radius1 + radius2 ) ) 
{
      //Do whatever you want here.
}
```

EDIT: I agree with the comments above, this class should not be a thread though.